# (C++) How to use GetPixel() of x y on screen

Tags: c++, getpixel

Could someone make some code that gets the pixel of an x y coord on screen and explain how the code works. I have read other examples but I dont know what all the functions and code do. Thanks.

Comment: get pixel of what? there are lots of devices and platforms in the world. The way to do it in Windows is definitely different from Linux

Comment: Hi, take a look at the [tour] and [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HDC hdcScreen = GetDC(0);
COLORREF crPixel = GetPixel(hdcScreen, 10, 10);
ReleaseDC(0, hdcScreen);
```

Will store the displayed pixel at coordinates 10,10 into crPixel.

Is this what you were asking for?